# Web API required field model validations not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-validation

I have a rather strange issue. The required field model validations  don't seem to work. The reason being we are using custom JSON deserializers which adds the default values to all the value types like integers,GUIDs etc. But the same works fine on string or anyother nullable types. I don't want to make my fields nullable. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

The simple and dirty way of doing this (might not be suitable in all scenarios) is to write custom validators for all value types you want to validate and check for their default values e.g.: for guid data type the default value is `Guid.Empty`.